# ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection: NullReferenceException trying to access concrete class member defined in its interface

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, controller, asp.net-core-webapi

this is getting weird as I've done it several times with no issues.
I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 for the record.
The problem is that I register a concrete type and its relative interface in the ConfigureServices Startup method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
             Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase")
            ));

        ProfileManager.RegisterMappingService(services);

        services.AddScoped<IUserWorkerService, UserWorkerService>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
        services.AddControllers();
```

I inject that dependency in the controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserWorkerService userWorkerService;

    public UsersController(IUserWorkerService userWorkerService)
    {
        this.userWorkerService = userWorkerService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userWorkerService));
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("authenticate")]
    public IActionResult Authenticate(string userName, string password)
    {
        var user = this.userWorkerService.Authenticate(userName.Trim(), password.Trim());

        if (user == null)
            return Unauthorized();
        return Ok(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(user));
    }
}
```

This is the interface:

```
    public interface IUserWorkerService
{
    public UserDto Authenticate(string userName, string password);
}
```

And this is the concrete class:

```
public class UserWorkerService : IUserWorkerService
{
    private readonly MyDbContext dbContext;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public UserWorkerService(MyDbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public UserDto Authenticate(string userName, string password)
    {
*blah blah*
    }
}
```

And when I make the POST request, I land correctly on the ActionResult of the controller but the UserWorkerService instance doesn't contain the member defined in its interface, just the injected members IMapper and MyDbContext.
[image]

Therefore, when code reaches Authenticate method invoke in the UsersController, debugger throws a NullReferenceException.
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Which line exactly is the error being thrown? within the service or directly in the conroller action?

Comment: In the controller action. I'll add a screenshot

Comment: And you are certain username and password are not null?

Comment: Are you parameters being read [FromBody] or FromQueryString, it would affect the binding of these parameters

Comment: My bad, u are right, I deleted mistakingly FromBody attribute...but problem is that in raw mode I think I cannot concatenate 2 parameters unless they are query string parameters.
This way I cannot use a JSON, like this:
{
 "username": "user", 
 "password": "password"
}

I should better use a ViewModel/Dto probably

Comment: @DioBrando If the content is coming from the body then use a single model and the appropriate attributes. So are you confirming that the issue is that the parameters are null?

Comment: The problem initially was a mismatch with signature call that was in my solution (1 parameter only, not 2 username+password), and then parameters weren't actually read from Body.
Thx guys

Comment: @DioBrando Glad to help. Consider self removing the post given the identified outcome.